# PYW not working

Tags: python, pythonw

I made a python script that would simple take and save a screenshot when ran. In the tutorial it said if I changed the file extension to .pyw it would still save a screenshot but it is not working. What might I be overlooking? I have it defaulted to run through pythonw and tried running it thought both programs on 2.7 and 3.6

```
    from PIL  import ImageGrab
    import os
    import time

    x_pad = 69
    y_pad = 23

    def screenGrab():
        box = (x_pad+1,y_pad+1,x_pad+1531,y_pad+877)
        im = ImageGrab.grab(    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\screenshot' + str(int(time.time())) +
        '.png', 'PNG')box)

    def main():
        screenGrab()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: does it run with just `.py`?

Comment: I have tried running them with both 2.7 and 3.6 Python and pythonw programs. They capture, but only from IDLE and pycharm.

Comment: so no one can think of a reason my module would run successfully in Idle but not perform a capture from explorer double clicking or opening with python and pythonw?